# Нужно составить программу используя for с учетом того, что массивы использовать нельзя и предусмотреть обработку неправильно введенных значений

Tags: c++

Условие следующее вывести сумму квадратов соседних чисел от 12 до 80 по одному числу в строке.
Не могу разобраться как заставить вывести сумму квадратов соседних чисел в этом промежутке.
Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот что имею на данный момент:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
int i;
{
cout << "Сумма квадратов соседних чисел в промежутке от 12 до 80:" << endl;
for (i = 12; i <= 80; ++i)
cout << 2*(i*i+1) << '\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 11; i <= 81; i++)` почему от 11 до 81 включительно? если в условии от 12 до 80?

Comment: Честно говоря мне вот непонятно, что такое " сумма квадратов соседних чисел". Каждая из пары соседних чисел должна так вычисляться, то есть на выходе некая последовательность чисел, а не одно число?

Comment: @CrazyElf, формальный семантический анализ фразы "вывести сумму квадратов соседних чисел от 12 до 80 по одному числу в строке" говорит, что должна быть выведена последовательность. На это указывает предлог "по".

Comment: не понятно условие, высказанная абстрактно. Что такое "соседних"? Где пример ответа? Где официальная задача?

Comment: Задание дано такое: написать программу используя оператор for. Массивы не использовать. Предусмотреть обработку неправильно введённых значений.
Условие задания: Вывести сумму квадратов соседних чисел от 12 до 80 по одному числу в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала можете  написать простой подсчет суммы квадратов соседних чисел:

```
 for (unsigned a = 12; a < 80; ++a) 
    cout << 2 * a * (a + 1) + 1 << '\n';
```

Потому, что: a^2 + (a + 1)^2 =

```
         a^2 + a^2 + 2 * a + 1 = 
         2 * a^2 + 2 * a + 1 = 
         2 * (a^2 + a) + 1 =
         2 * a * ( a + 1) + 1
```

Comment: а у меня получилось `2*(a*a+1)`. как вы узрели этот ответ?

Comment: спасибо огромное AR Hovsepyan и за правку @AlexGlebe

Comment: @AlexGlebe, a^2 + (a + 1) ^2 = a^2 + a^2 + 2 * a + 1 = 2 * a ^ 2 + 2 * a + 1 = 2 * (a^2 + a) + 1 = 2 * a * ( a + 1) + 1

Comment: А как предусмотреть правильность ввода значений, если мне надо ввести с клавиатуры 12 и 80?

Comment: `(a-1)^2+(a+1)^2=a^2+1+a^2+1=2*(a^2+1)`